# how to convert xml to array with different node into one single array

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

in this xml there is windows inside window there is window i want to read window which name is feedback.
and want to make array of it in the same sequence as we have text and control node inside window
so i want to make one array like in 0 index text should come and the 1 index ctrol then again text and then control.

the desire output is

```
$output=array(
"text"=>'Usa enteros en una recta num',
"text"=>'Use Impy',
"control"=>'F3',
"text"=>'rica para representar la situaci',
"control"=>'F1',
"text"=>'n. Decide qu',
"control"=>'F3',
"text"=>' quiere decir la palabra clave &#34;gast',
"control"=>'F1',
"text"=>' &#34;.'
); 


$xmlDocument='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tdx version="1.0">
  <meta name="created" value="2016-04-15T20:11:42Z"/>
  <meta name="atversion" value="4.10.15.13"/>
  <meta name="attype" value="DeltaAT"/>
  <meta name="currency" value="dollar"/>
  <meta name="numberpts" value="1"/>
  <meta name="toleranceallowed" value="yes"/>
  <meta name="desc" value="4/15/2016 SE_GEXdev - new for envG7R.1.1.AP-2 (static EX/SP)"/>
  <meta name="format" value="static"/>
  <meta name="saved" value="2017-12-22T15:15:55Z"/>
  <meta name="objects" value="field,formula"/>
  <meta name="qtype" value="SA"/>
  <meta name="problemtype" value="exercise"/>
  <toolbuttons names="over,mnum,super,abs,sqrt,nroot,sub,pair"/>

  <styles/>

  <objects>
    <field name="S1" format="" rule="numeric">
      <solution>
        <expr>27</expr>
      </solution>
      <defmsgwrong cw="70" ch="0">
        <display step="wrong1"/>
      </defmsgwrong>
    </field>
    <formula name="F1">
      <expr>ó</expr>
    </formula>
    <formula name="F2">
      <expr>í</expr>
    </formula>
    <formula name="F3">
      <expr>é</expr>
    </formula>
  </objects>

  <windows>
    <window name="top">
      <step name="step1">
<rvxml>
<document stringtags="0">
<text>Escribe el entero que representa la situaci</text>
<control br="0" vshiftabs="1" spacing="1" textstyle="Normal" data="">F1</control>
<text br="0">n.</text>
<text></text>
<text>Trevor gast</text>
<control br="0" vshiftabs="1" spacing="1" textstyle="Normal" data="">F1</control>
<text br="0"> $27 y ahora no le queda dinero. Ten</text>
<control br="0" vshiftabs="1" spacing="1" textstyle="Normal" data="">F2</control>
<text br="0">a $___ antes de su compra.</text>
</document>
</rvxml>
      </step>
    </window>
    <window name="bottom">
      <step name="step2">
<rvxml>
<document stringtags="0">
<text>Ten</text>
<control br="0" vshiftabs="1" spacing="1" textstyle="Normal" data="">F2</control>
<text br="0">a $</text>
<control br="0" vshiftabs="1" spacing="1" textstyle="Normal" data="">S1</control>
<text br="0"> antes de su compra.</text>
</document>
</rvxml>
      </step>
    </window>
    **<window name="feedback">
      <step name="wrong1">
<rvxml>
<document stringtags="0">
<text>Usa enteros en una recta num</text>
<text>Use Impy</text>
<control br="0" vshiftabs="1" spacing="1" textstyle="Normal" data="">F3</control>
<text br="0">rica para representar la situaci</text>
<control br="0" vshiftabs="1" spacing="1" textstyle="Normal" data="">F1</control>
<text br="0">n. Decide qu</text>
<control br="0" vshiftabs="1" spacing="1" textstyle="Normal" data="">F3</control>
<text br="0"> quiere decir la palabra clave &#34;gast</text>
<control br="0" vshiftabs="1" spacing="1" textstyle="Normal" data="">F1</control>
<text br="0">&#34;.</text>
</document>
</rvxml>
      </step>
    </window>**
    <window name="popups"/>
  </windows>

  <layout type="topbottom">
    <frame window="top"/>
    <frame window="bottom"/>
  </layout>

  <controller>
    <display step="step1"/>
    <display step="step2"/>
  </controller>

</tdx>';




$people = simplexml_load_string($xmlDocument);
echo "<pre>";print_r($people);exit();
```

part of output im getting is

```
[2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => feedback
                                )

                            [step] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => wrong1
                                        )

                                    [rvxml] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [document] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [stringtags] => 0
                                                        )

                                                    [text] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Usa enteros en una recta num
                                                            [1] => rica para representar la situaci
                                                            [2] => n. Decide qu
                                                            [3] =>  quiere decir la palabra clave "gast
                                                            [4] => ".
                                                        )

                                                    [control] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => F3
                                                            [1] => F1
                                                            [2] => F3
                                                            [3] => F1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )
```

here im getting control and text both in separate array but i want both text and control in the same array in same sequence

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? It's good that you've posted example data and output, but please post your code/attempt as well and what currently happens (we need details, incl. full error messages, if any.) Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that was recommended to you when you registered.

Comment: i have added  the code and output im getting

Comment: The keys in an array must be unique. Check out what PHP does with your array here https://3v4l.org/jLXQE ! Reconsider your question.

Answer (score 0):

Mixed nodes are to complex for SimpleXML - use DOM.

However keys in an array have to be unique. You will have to nest arrays to store the data.

```php
// bootstrap dom
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getXMLString());
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// fetch the nodes using xpath
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate(
  '//window[@name="feedback"]/step/rvxml/document/*'
);

$result = [];
// iterate the nodes and store the values into an array
foreach($nodes as $node) {
  $result[] = [
    'kind' => $node->localName,
    'content' => $node->textContent 
  ];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["kind"]=>
    string(4) "text"
    ["content"]=>
    string(28) "Usa enteros en una recta num"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["kind"]=>
    string(4) "text"
    ["content"]=>
    string(8) "Use Impy"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["kind"]=>
    string(7) "control"
    ["content"]=>
    string(2) "F3"
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Im getting one issue. the xml is given abobe im fetching it from db storing in one variable and passing that variable loadxml but its not working but if same string im passing as hardcoded then its working fine

Comment: Sounds like an encoding problem somewhere. Like the database connection. The string might not be valid UTF-8. Or it is truncated at some point.

Comment: Try to catch the XML parsing errors using the libxml functions. This should provide you an idea.